# WIFI, Lan & Audio not working after update of windows 10

Tags: windows, audio, drivers, ethernet, windows-10-upgrade

My issue is that my WiFi and Ethernet adapters and audio device are not working.  My laptop is `LENOVO Z580`, I have windows 10 after upgrading from Windows 8.1.

Windows have new update and i updated this and my WiFi, Ethernet and audio is not working.  I have tried to my best of my ability to install the correct drive but my problem is not going away.

In Device Manager , all drivers are completely installed. however this drivers are not works. Here is a screenshot of my device manager:

[image]

Comment: Please provide specific driver versions, even though there is no evidence you have the wrong drivers installed, it is still information we might need.

Answer (score -2):

So i tried a number of these "fixes" the two above did not work for me at all as i do not have VPN software. I uninstalled my Antivirus not luck, Disabled my firewall no luck, started removing recent programs no luck.

DO NOT INSTALL THE CRAP THAT IS DRIVER TALENT! IT NEEDS INTERNET AND REGISTRATION!

Remembered i have installed a XBOX one wireless controller adapter recently found it had put some 2003 C++ software on so began uninstalling this with Ccleaner! BOOM!! worked!

hope this helps.